# Mouse cursor stops working Razer Naga

Tags: mouse

Still new to Linux for the most part (been taking a Udemy course).

Anyways, having an issue with my Razer Naga. About every 10-15 seconds the mouse cursor freezes. Then somewhere between 2-5 seconds later it unfreezes.

While the cursor is frozen, the buttons on the mouse continue to work. I can right and left click the desktop.

I have used this mouse on Windows with no issues. Seems to be a Ubuntu issue.

Anyways, any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Had a similar issue but without buttons working, the mouse was just completely dead for a few seconds. Re-installing the driver/upgrading worked, but still having issues with mouse freezing in Steam/Youtube.